# fail2ban does not ban one address

Tags: linux, fail2ban

all. I just installed fail2ban 0.11.2 and it seems to run. All settings are default.
Looking into its log file I see that from qpsmtpd analysis there is one address which it doesn't want to ban, although other addresses (in the same qpsmtpd log) are banned as required. Here is the log copy:

```
2022-09-11 21:31:03,696 fail2ban.filter         [1299]: INFO    [qpsmtpd] Found 5.34.207.48 - 2022-09-11 21:31:03
2022-09-11 21:33:31,672 fail2ban.filter         [1299]: INFO    [qpsmtpd] Found 5.34.207.48 - 2022-09-11 21:33:31
2022-09-11 21:36:10,064 fail2ban.filter         [1299]: INFO    [qpsmtpd] Found 5.34.207.48 - 2022-09-11 21:36:10
2022-09-11 21:38:38,204 fail2ban.filter         [1299]: INFO    [qpsmtpd] Found 5.34.207.48 - 2022-09-11 21:38:38
2022-09-11 21:41:03,928 fail2ban.filter         [1299]: INFO    [qpsmtpd] Found 5.34.207.48 - 2022-09-11 21:41:03
2022-09-11 21:43:28,399 fail2ban.filter         [1299]: INFO    [qpsmtpd] Found 5.34.207.48 - 2022-09-11 21:43:28
2022-09-11 21:46:06,612 fail2ban.filter         [1299]: INFO    [qpsmtpd] Found 5.34.207.48 - 2022-09-11 21:46:06
2022-09-11 21:48:42,169 fail2ban.filter         [1299]: INFO    [qpsmtpd] Found 5.34.207.48 - 2022-09-11 21:48:42
2022-09-11 21:51:11,410 fail2ban.filter         [1299]: INFO    [qpsmtpd] Found 5.34.207.48 - 2022-09-11 21:51:11
2022-09-11 21:53:50,462 fail2ban.filter         [1299]: INFO    [qpsmtpd] Found 5.34.207.48 - 2022-09-11 21:53:50
2022-09-11 21:56:20,768 fail2ban.filter         [1299]: INFO    [qpsmtpd] Found 5.34.207.48 - 2022-09-11 21:56:20
2022-09-11 21:58:57,079 fail2ban.filter         [1299]: INFO    [qpsmtpd] Found 5.34.207.48 - 2022-09-11 21:58:57
```

Is there something I missed?
Thanks.

Update: To be on the safe side I updated the settings as FindTime=900 and MaxRetry=3.

Comment: If everything is configured as default, the value of "findtime" is set to 10m and "maxretry" to 5 which means an host is getting banned if it makes 5 attempts within 10 mins. In your case the fifth attempt seems to happens after 10mins, I guess this is the reason why is not banning that host

Comment: Thank you, DarkVex, but all the manuals I saw speak about FindTime=15m and MaxRetry=3. To be on the safe side I set them manually to these values.
Still, this IP is not banned.

Comment: This is another demonstration why `recidive` jail is a must. Brute forcing bots became more intelligent and they are now able to accurately test and find out your fail2ban parameters and play just to not be banned.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the solution.
The configuration file has different maxretries for each protocol.
The default value for qpsmtpd was 9 for some reason.
Changing this to 3 solved the issue.